# using ngx-charts and loading data from an observable

Tags: angular, observable, ngx-charts

So I'm trying to make a simple bar chart like [this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vertical-bar-chart?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts) (see [documentation](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/bar-charts/vertical-bar-chart)).

I'm getting my data from an observable and trying to run change detection in the subscription because the data isn't showing up in the chart, but change detection isn't doing the trick. How do I get the data to show up in the chart if it isn't loaded until after the view initializes?

Here's my code:

**bar-chart.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataLoadingService } from "../data-loading.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.scss']
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {

  subscription: any;
  data: any;
  results: any[] = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataLoadingService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.subscription = this.dataService.source.subscribe((val: any) => {
        this.data = val.body;
        for(let x = 0; x < this.data.length; x++) {
            let match = false;
            for(let y = 0; y < this.results.length; y++) {
                if (this.results[y]["name"] === this.data[x].outcome_level) {
                    match = true;
                    this.results[y]["value"] += 1;
                }
            }
            if(match === false) {
                this.results.push({"name": this.data[x].outcome_level, "value": 1})
            }
        }
        function compare(a: any, b: any) {
            if(a.name > b.name) return 1;
            if(a.name < b.name) return -1;

            return 0;
        }

        this.results.sort(compare);
        console.log(this.results);
        this.ref.detectChanges();
      } );
    console.log("from onInit: " + this.results);
  }
```

The output of the first console.log is as follows:

```
0: {name: "1", value: 3}
1: {name: "2", value: 6}
2: {name: "3", value: 1}
3: {name: "4", value: 2}
```

The output of console.log("from onInit: " + this.results) is empty

**bar-chart.component.html**

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical
  [results]="results"
  xAxis=true
  yAxis=true
  gradient=false
  legend=true
  showXAxisLabel=true
  showYAxisLabel=true
  xAxisLabel="OutcomeLevel"
  yAxisLabel="NumberOfProjects"
></ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

Comment: `console.log("from onInit: " + this.results)` is returning nothing because your subscribe is called asynchronous and your console.log is not waiting your observable to finish. But, you are populating your results correctly...do you see some data on your chart? Inspect your chart and check the `this.results`, maybe is just not right data format?

Comment: I've checked the data format, it's an array of objects that have two properties, `name`, a string, and `value`, a number. I don't see any data on the chart and that's what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. You don't need ref.detectChanges(). It updates data after u change it. Can u create stackblitz example of your code?

Comment: this is my first time ever using stackblitz. Does this suffice?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmgmk8

Comment: I don't know why it's having an issue parsing the JSON file right now, I apologize for that @pc_coder

Comment: I'm not getting that error in my application, and I've triple checked and the json file should be formatted correctly now.

Comment: @pc_coder have you had a chance to look at this today? I'm hoping to have this small prototype finished by Wednesday

Answer (score 1):

hello i had the same issue as yours , i managed to get a workaround :

- 1 - add a new variable to your *bar-chart.component.ts* ( ex : dataReceived = false)
- 2 - change the value of dataReceived to true at the of the subscribe methode
- 3 - then *bar-chart.component.html* use *ngif(dataReceived) to render the chart

it seems that change detection doesn't work inside subscribe methode
(Ps : it's only my conclusion and i'm new in Angular ^^)